# UIPageViewController from scratch

Tags: uipageviewcontroller

I would like to get a handle on implementing the UIPageViewController from scratch using no XIB or WYSIWYG Interface Builder template storyboard style approaches.  Any book or link references would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the description in the "[View Controller Catalog for IOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html)"?